# string in webclient class c# changed to uncorrect format

Tags: web-services, wcf, model-view-controller, utf-8

I call my service in wcf as you can see :

```
  ClientRequest.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
            string result = ClientRequest.DownloadString(ServiceHostName + "/NajaService.svc/GetCarData/" + plaque);

            var javascriptserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return javascriptserializer.Deserialize<NajaResult>(result);
```

But the returned data is like this :

```
{"CarColor":"Ø¢Ø¨ÙŠ Ø³ÙŠØ±","CarModel":"1383","CarTip":"Ø§Ù„ Ø§ÙŠÚ©Ø³","CarType":"Ø³ÙˆØ§Ø±ÙŠ","Chassis":"83844131","Family":"####","FuelType":1,"MotorNum":"12483068683","Name":"####","NationalCode":"0000000000","Plaque":"11-426Ø¯61","PlaqueCoded":110561426,"PlaqueType":"","SystemType":"Ø³Ù…Ù†Ø¯","VinNo":"IRFC831V3GJ844131"}
```

I converted it to UTF8 byte and again convert it to utf8 string but not solved.

The encoded data is in Persian language .

I traced the request in fiddler and i found that the data is come with the correct format as you can see ,But in my code is changed

[image]

Comment: have you tried to deserialize it  with JsonSerializer?

Comment: Yes i have ,the deserialize  returns incorrect string too

Comment: if the ClientRequest in you code is WebClient - there is an Encoding property there - you can try to setup it

Comment: @RomanAnanyev Could you please give me in details ?

Comment: here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RomanAnanyev thank you it works dear friend

Comment: @RomanAnanyev post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WebRequest` contains the `Encoding` property you can set up before downloading the service reply. Details are here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx