# C# : When calling PHP webservice : The content type text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1

Tags: c#, php, web-services

I am consuming a PHP webservice as below

```
http://xxxxx.com/api/soapservice.php?wsdl
```

and consuming the same as below

```
        team.obj r = new team.obj();
        team.trackdata data = new team.trackdata();
        data.BookingNumber = "1223232";
        data.CompanyCode = "0012";
        r.GetStatusDetails(data);
```

at `r.GetStatusDetails(data);` I am getting the below error

> The content type text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1 of the response message
>   does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml;
>   charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the
>   IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024
>   bytes of the response were:

Comment: could you review this - it could be the same solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623272/string-in-webclient-class-c-sharp-changed-to-uncorrect-format/44623700#44623700

Comment: @RomanAnanyev hw to implement that in my code?

Comment: looks like you should do the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908030/calling-a-webservice-that-uses-iso-8859-1-encoding-from-wcf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a webservice that uses ISO-8859-1 encoding from WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908030/calling-a-webservice-that-uses-iso-8859-1-encoding-from-wcf)